# Tornado IOLoop is waken infinitely by EPOLLOUT taking 100% CPU usage

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, tornado, epoll, strace

I am using `tornado 4.4.1` in `Ubuntu 14.xx` for `Websocket` and `HTTP` server.

I have run it for a couple of days.

In the meantime, I found that the IoLoop thread takes 100% CPU usage.

I check what action the thread do though `strace -p IoLoopthreadId`.

The trace is saying that `IoLoop` is waken infinitely from `epoll_wait` by `EPOLLOUT`.

I just use `ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()` to produce `IoLoop` Thread.

What can it make this situation?

How can I solve it ?

Please give me any suggestions.

[image]

**------------------EDIT---------------------**

The below is the part of code regarding Tornado.

Additionally, what if end-point(websocket) is in no response state keeping connection while tornado tries to send a message, does it probably make this problem case?

```
class ConvPlayerInterface(object):

    logger = logging.getLogger("Player.PlayerInterface")
    queue = ipcQueue.IpcQueue(maxsize=50)

    class WebsocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):

        client = []

        def open(self):
            ConvPlayerInterface.logger.info('PlayerInterface is Opened')
            self.client.append(self)      #It consider that only one client is handled. 

        def on_message(self, message):
            ConvPlayerInterface.logger.info("Receive PlayerInterface Message : %s" % message)
            ConvPlayerInterface.queue.put(message)

        def on_close(self):
            ConvPlayerInterface.logger.info('PlayerInterface is closed')
            self.client.remove(self)

        def check_origin(self, origin):
            return True

    def get(self):
        jsonStr = self.queue.get()
        return json.loads(jsonStr)

    def getAll(self):
        jsonStrList = self.queue.getAll()
        jsonObjList = [json.loads(_jsonStr) for _jsonStr in jsonStrList]
        return jsonObjList

    def put(self, command):
        for client in self.WebsocketHandler.client:
            client.write_message(command)
            ConvPlayerInterface.logger.info('Emitted PlayerInterface Message : %s' % command)


    def execute(self, command, rtnCmd):
        pass


class TornadoManager(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, location):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        _djangoWsgi = djangoWsgi.get_wsgi_application()
        self.tornadoWsgiContainer= tornadoWsgi.WSGIContainer(_djangoWsgi)
        self.ip, self.port = location.split(":")

        self.tornadoApp =  web.Application([   
                                            (r"/list/socket", playerInterface.ConvPlayerInterface.WebsocketHandler),
                                            (r'/static/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")}),
                                            (r".*", web.FallbackHandler, dict(fallback=self.tornadoWsgiContainer)),
                                            ], debug=False
                                           )

        self.server = httpserver.HTTPServer(self.tornadoApp)
        self.server.listen(self.port, self.ip)


    def run(self):
        print "Start Tornado IOLoop - %s:%s" % (self.ip, self.port)
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal code example, that still results in 100% CPU usage?

Comment: @hruske Thank you for your attention, I add the part of code and comment on a suspicious case.

Comment: Tornado does not use threading for multitasking. If you are using them, they may make your process behave in strange ways unless you don't take special care.

Comment: @hruske As you can see, in `get` method of `class ConvPlayerInterface`  have access to websocket objects `self.WebsocketHandler.client` and the thread which call this method is another thread not being IoLoop thread, does it make problem?. If so how can I start message from server side?,  I think IoLoop thread is just to wait for a message and send the response not to start message?

Comment: In the `strace` output, the `epoll` calls alternate with `send()` calls that send an empty message to file descriptor 42. What is file descriptor 42 pointing to? You can use `lsof` to find out (the number 42 will probably change the next time you run this, but you want whichever number appears in the `send()` calls)

Comment: @asleea Don't use threads. Remove `threading.Thread`, remove `threading.Thread.__init__` call. Tornado does not use threads.